# EKS Service Account Annotation

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a service account, and this needs access to multiple aws services. Is there any way we could specify multiple role an annotations, or do we expect to create a generic role and give access to all the required services?

The below not supported?

[image]

ChatGPT says,

```html
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: my-service-account
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-role-1
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/my-role-2
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  You can't use PNG files as Kubernetes configuration at all; can you [edit] the question to include plain-text YAML instead?

Comment: Just in general, I don't think you're ever allowed to have multiple AWS IAM roles; I think you can only attach one role to an EC2 instance, for example, and if you use the Amazon APIs to switch roles, the new credentials have only the new role in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its not supported like what you shown.

example supported:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xxxx
```

your options is to use 1 iam role arn like above, with multiple IAM policy attached. I don't think its hard to add multiple policy to a role.

Comment: Its possible to attach multiple policies to a role. But our idea is least privilege, reusability and granularity. In that case, we maintain different roles. As per our standards, we don't create custom roles per requirement. so we have two roles that satisfies the requirement. ChatGPT says this an option (updated question) which I dont think possible as duplicate keys.

Comment: yes, I believe its not possible too,
well hard fact tho, that we need to maintain 1 role per serviceaccount with one / more policies